# Check if URI actually exists .NET

Tags: .net, uri, webrequest, httpwebresponse

I want to check programmatically if an URL actually exists. The URL's I check are calls to a WebAPI server so they have different HTTP Methods. What I do first is actually check if the Uri is well formed and than I call this method I created. Let me first tell you I totally dislike this method but it seems to do it's job. Am I missing something important here that I should check or is there are better cleaner way instead of this exception logic. I only want to know if the URL exists, nothing more nothing less. So most of the time I'm getting 405 Method Not Allowed and that is fine.

```
    public static bool UriExists(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Timeout = 5000;
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            return ((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NotFound &&
                   ((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout &&
                   ((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your method would return `true` if the 5s timeout happened.

Comment: Changed my code thx !!